# Notifications or setting for notifications for reputation changes on mobile app

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, android-app, notifications

Why does the mobile app not notify the user that reputation has changed. For example, if someone has upvoted (or voted down) the question, wouldn't someone like to know? At least it should be a setting in the app that says 'Allow notifications for messages only', or 'Allow notifications' - something like that.

Why does this feature not exist?